# Resources for creating complex entities?

Tags: 8, entities, database

I have been working with Symfony 2-3 from the developer perspective, where you are able to create complex entities with various relation types (many-to-one, many-to-many, one-to-one) easily. Also these entities have multiple relations and can be added/edited/deleted/read via short and handy class methods.

Example for a complex entities:

- "product entity" has a one-to-many relation to "color entity"
- "color entity" has a many-to-many relation to "color structure" entity

See entity associations in Doctrine: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

Another benefit in Doctrine is, that the entities are structured with primary-foreign-key pairs. They allow you, to easily inspect the relations via your database schema by a database tool like MySQL Workbench.

I do not want to use Doctrine inside of Drupal 8. I want to use Drupal entities. However it seems more complicated than in Doctrine and I am searching for some guidance.

In Drupal 8 I see just resources for simple entities. Like the content entity example in the "Examples for Developers" module: https://www.drupal.org/project/examples. There's just 1 relation from 1 contact entity to the user entity.

If I inspect the Drupal 8 database schema, there are no primary-foreign-key pairs. By digging in the code of the Drupal 8 core entities, I see just the "entity_reference" field type. There's no one-to-one, many-to-many or one-to-many relationship. It seems that Drupal entities are just so far behind the entities in Doctrine. Right now it seems like a mess, to inspect any data via a database tool like MySQL Workbench.

So I am asking myself, how am I able to practically work with "complex entities" in Drupal? How do I get an overview of my complex entities structure and how do I create them at all? How can I limit the association types (one-to-many, many-to-many etc.)?

Should I be using a REST api into Symfony to build complex entities?

I have been checking the ERD project at https://www.drupal.org/project/erd, but it seems that this project is dead and it has not been working in my tests.

Any sources which would enable to efficiently work with Drupal 8 entities would be appreciated. Please be so kind and share a bit of your resources in working with Drupal 8 entities.

Comment: I am not asking for using Doctrine in Drupal 8. I am mentioning Doctrine just as an example for entity handling.

Comment: The documentation for drupal entities is linked in the answer.

Comment: ERD has got a new release just a few hours ago

Comment: @4k4 this question is relevant to the one you linked.